# FileReader.onload can not return successful in time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the image file stream and pass them to the background like asp.net,but every time I try to fire the onload event ,it always accomplish after the programming passed.

I tried to use setTimeout to prevent it and let it processing and waiting it Success ,but it failed .
the comment of below explains which step I failed.thanks.

```
 $("#goodsImage").change(function (e) {
        if ($("#goodsImage").val() == "")
        {
            alert("please choose the image you want to upload");
            return;
        }

        var filepath = $("#goodsImage").val();

        //$("#goodsImage").val();
        var extStart=filepath.lastIndexOf(".");
        var ext=filepath.substring(extStart,filepath.length).toUpperCase();
        if(ext!=".BMP"&&ext!=".PNG"&&ext!=".GIF"&&ext!=".JPG"&&ext!=".JPEG"){
            alert("only images could be uploaded");
            return;
        }
        readFile(e.target.files[0]);
        setTimeout(function () {
            //I want to use setTimeOut to delay it
        }, 1000);


       //always undefined!!!
       if ($("#hidImageStream").val() != "")
       {
           $.post("@Url.Action("UploadGoodImage")", { localPath: readerRs }, function (e)
           {
               if (e) {
                   $("#ImagePreviewUrl").val(e.data);
               }
               else {

               }
           });
       }



    });

    function readFile(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = readSuccess;

        //always success after post request accomplished.
        function readSuccess(evt) {

            document.getElementById("hidImageStream").
                value = evt.target.result;

        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
```

Comment: you don't fire onload, it fires itself when the file is fully loaded into the reader

Comment: @dandavis of course you are right ,I solved it by myself ,look at the answer I replied by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a few tips

```
<-- use accept and only allow image mimetype. It can accept extension to -->
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
```

- Also reading the file as `readAsText` is a horrible idea for binary. (All doe i saw you change to base64).
- `readAsDataURL` isn't that grate either since it's ~3x larger upload and needs more cpu/memory.
- Spoofing the filename is very easy so best is to actually test if it's a image

```
$("#goodsImage").change(function() {
    // We use `this` to access the DOM element instead of target
    for (let file of this.files) {
        // Test if it's a image instead of looking at the filename
        let img = new image
        img.onload = () => {
            // Success it's a image
            // upload file
            let fd = new FormData
            fd.append('file', file)

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://example.com',
                data: fd,
                processData: false, // so jquery can handle FormData
                type: 'POST',
                success: function( data ) {
                    alert( data )
                }
            })
        }

        img.onerror = () => {
            // only images dude
        }

        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the question ,just put the post request into the onloaded funciton .

```
 function readFile(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = readSuccess;
        //reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        //    console.log(e.target.result);
        //};

        function readSuccess(evt) {
            $.post("@Url.Action("UploadGoodImage")", { localPath: evt.target.result}, function (e) {
            if (e.IsSuccess) {
                $("#ImagePreviewUrl").val(e.data);
            }
            else {
                alert("Fail！");
            }

        });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```